# I do not see console.log in my Beaker job

Tags: linux, automated-tests, beaker-testing

My Beaker job is running, and I see other logs but I do not see `console.log`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Beaker looks for the test system's console log in a file `<system fqdn>` in the directory `/var/consoles` on the lab controller to which the system is attached to.

The specific daemon process that handles this is the `beaker-watchdog` daemon . If this daemon is running, but doesn't find a file `<system fqdn>`, the Beaker job running on this system will **not** have a `console.log` file. This directory or file may not exist, either due to a [console logging solution](https://beaker-project.org/docs/architecture-guide/capabilities.html#log-collection-monitoring-and-archiving) not configured at all or misconfigured.

To summarize, the things to check in this case:

1. `beaker-watchdog` is running
2. `/var/consoles` exist on the lab controller to which the system belongs
3. The file `/var/consoles/<system fqdn>` exist